# Unexpected output of operator<< in C++ class and replace union by std::variant, std::visit

Tags: c++, refactoring

Currently, my code can produce correct output if I declare class object with arguments in main() directly. But when I declare class to an instance to output by operator<< , it get incorrect result. I'd appreciate if someone can help me fix this issue.

Here's my main() that get correct string

```
int main() {
    
    Product dieselMotorBike("A Diesel Motor Cycle", 5488.00, 1);
    Product apples("Granny duBois", 0.78, 2);       
}
```

Output:

```
A Diesel Motor Cycle
Granny duBois
```

Here's my full code that uses operator<< to print:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include<functional>

using namespace std;

// std::variant<int, float> units, kgs;
using Var = std::variant<int, float>;

typedef union {
   int units;
   float kgs;
} Amount;


class Product {

    public:
        char* selling;
        unsigned length;
        float unitPrice;
        int unitType;
        Amount howMuch;
        Var v;
        // Constructor without arguments 
        Product();
        
        // Constructor with arguments
        Product(const char* s, float unitPrice, int unitType);
        
        ~Product() { delete[] selling; }
        
        /*! 
         *  @brief String length.
         *  @return Value in String @c length.
         */
        unsigned len ( ) const;
    
        /*! 
         *  @brief Append to String.
         *  @param[in] s A String object.
         *  @return A String reference to *this.
         *  @post String will equal the concatenation of itself with @a s.
          */
        Product& operator+= (const Product& s);
    
        char& operator[](size_t idx);
        char operator[](size_t idx) const;
    
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Product& s) {
           os.write(s.selling, s.length);
            return os;
        }
    
        // Return string length
        int size() { return length; }
};

// Constructor with no arguments
Product::Product() : selling{new char[1] {'\0'}}, unitPrice{0.00}, unitType{0} {}

// Constructor with one argument
Product::Product(const char* s, float unitPrice, int unitType) {
    if (s == nullptr) {
        selling = new char[1]{'\0'};
        length = 0;
        this->unitPrice = 0.00;
        this->unitType = 0;
    } else {
        length = std::strlen(s);
        selling = new char[length + 1];
        std::copy(s, s + length + 1, selling);
        this->unitPrice = unitPrice;
        this->unitType = unitType;
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
}

unsigned Product::len ( ) const 
{
    return length;
}

Product& Product::operator+=(const Product& s) {
    unsigned len = length + s.length;
    char* str = new char[len + 1];
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < length; j++) str[j] = selling[j];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.length; i++) str[length + i] = s.selling[i];
    str[len] = '\0';
    delete[] selling;
    length = len;
    selling = str;
    return *this;
}

Product operator+(const Product& lhs, const Product& rhs) {
    Product rv(lhs);
    rv += rhs;
    return rv;
}

char& Product::operator[](size_t idx) { return selling[idx]; }
char Product::operator[](size_t idx) const { return selling[idx]; }

int main() {
    int numItems = 2; int i;
    char temp1[] = "A Diesel Motor Cycle";
    char temp2[] = "Granny duBois";
    Product dieselMotorBike;
    Product apples;
    // dieselMotorBike.selling = temp1;
    strcpy(dieselMotorBike.selling, temp1);
    dieselMotorBike.unitPrice = 5488.00;
    dieselMotorBike.unitType = 1;
    dieselMotorBike.howMuch.units = 4;
    cout << dieselMotorBike << "\n";
    //Product apples("Granny duBois", 0.78, 2);
    Product * myEbayStore[2];
    
    strcpy(apples.selling, temp2);
    apples.unitPrice = 0.78;
    apples.unitType = 2;
    apples.howMuch.kgs = 0.5;
    cout << apples << "\n";
    
    myEbayStore[0] = &dieselMotorBike;
    myEbayStore[1] = &apples;
    for (i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
        printf("\n%s\n", myEbayStore[i]->selling);
        switch (myEbayStore[i]->unitType) {
            case 1:
                printf("We have %d units for sale\n",
                myEbayStore[i]->howMuch.units);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("We have %f kgs for sale\n",
                myEbayStore[i]->howMuch.kgs);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
A Diesel Motor Cycle!�
A Diesel Motor Cycle
We have 4 units for sale

Granny duBois
We have 0.500000 kgs for sale
```

It output more line of "A Diesel Motor Cycle". I even don't know how !� appeared in the 1st line. How to solve it?

Besides, I read some ways to replace union by std::variant, std::visit in the class, but don't know how to write it. Please show me sample code to replace it.

Comment: don't tag C when the question is about C++. In C++ you can use `std::string`, why don't you?

Comment: Yes, switch over to using `std::string` as @463035818_is_not_a_number recommends and the problem will likely go away.

Comment: your class fails to respect the rule of 3/5, here `Product rv(lhs);` and maybe elsewhere this is a problem. Using `std::string` will also fix that

Comment: do you mean change char* selling and temp1,temp2 to std:;string?

Comment: I assign string directly to selling and removed strcpy, it showed correct result, but also has this in the output message: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer. 
Besides, how to replace union by std::variant std::visit? I mentioned 2 issues.

Comment: Enable more warnings in the compiler and run your code through linters and static analyzers like Clang-tidy and Clang-analyzer. They will tell you the immediate cause of your problem (namely that your default constructor doesn't initialize `length`) as well as about other problems (e.g. rule-of-3) and also give recommendations for cleaner and more modern code. See https://godbolt.org/z/GrM9vTacE. (Not all of the diagnostics necessarily should be fixed, especially the `modernize-` ones, but you should give each one a thought. I think I filtered all of the specific style guideline diagnostics.)

Comment: The only thing you need to change for `std::variant` (besides removing `unitType` and switching from `howMuch` to `v`) is to replace the `switch` with `std::visit`. An example for how to use it can be found e.g. at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit.

Comment: Missing `Product(Product const&)` is causing problems.  Instead of rolling your own custom buggy string, you should use `std::string` which has been thoroughly debugged.